# How to use sumtable in R to get the summary stats for only a subset of observations

Tags: r, vtable

I have a data frame object that contains a subset of variables (model, mpg, year, etc.).

I created a data frame object from that only contains the first 200 observations called reducedset.

I am trying to make a summary statistics table that for only the model "cars" but I cannot figure it.  I referenced vtable.pdf but am still struggling.

```
st(reducedset, group='model', group.test=TRUE)
```

Comment: I am not using any models yet.  I am just trying to get basic summary stats (min, max, sd, mean) for a single vehicle type.

Comment: Below, I have written a function `my_stats()` which gives you the summary stats you mention per group of a certain `grouping_factor`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this. The following function termed `my_stats()` splits the subset of `mtcars` termed `sub` into groups of a `grouping_factor` (here: `vs`) and then computes the `mean`, `sd`, `min`, and `max` for each variable within `sub`.

```
# cars data
data(mtcars)

# random subset
sub <- mtcars[sample(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), 20, replace = TRUE), ]

# function to compute the mean and sd for variables in 'df' according
# to 'grouping_factor'
my_stats <- \(df, grouping_factor){
  sum_stats <- lapply(split(df, df[[grouping_factor]]), \(x) {
    data.frame(sapply(x, \(i) cbind(
      mean(i, na.rm = TRUE), sd(i, na.rm = TRUE),
      min(i, na.rm = TRUE), max(i, na.rm = TRUE))))
  })
  sum_stats <- lapply(sum_stats, \(x) {
    rownames(x) <- c('Mean', 'SD', 'Min', 'Max'); x
  })
  for(i in 1:length(sum_stats)) {
    names(sum_stats)[i] <-
      paste(grouping_factor, '=', levels(as.factor(df[[grouping_factor]]))[i])
  }
  return(sum_stats)
}
```

**Output** (for the first three columns in each group)

```
> lapply(my_stats(df = sub, grouping_factor = 'vs'), '[', 1:3)
$`vs = 0`
           mpg      cyl     disp
Mean 16.650000 7.500000 296.3833
SD    3.234333 0.904534  99.4829
Min  10.400000 6.000000 145.0000
Max  21.000000 8.000000 460.0000

$`vs = 1`
           mpg cyl      disp
Mean 24.350000   4 113.21250
SD    3.000952   0  22.39256
Min  21.500000   4  79.00000
Max  30.400000   4 146.70000
```

If you would like to see all the output, simply run `my_stats(df = sub, grouping_factor = 'vs')`.

Note: use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` if you use a version of R <4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your data, so I tried to run your analysis over the Auto dataset from the package `ISLR` (see Introduction to Statistical Learning, James et al., 2013). I replaced the condition `model == "cars"` with `year == 70`, but the reasoning is the same.

```
library(ISLR)
dta = Auto # Replace this with your data!
reducedset = dta[1:200, ]
st(reducedset[reducedset$year == 70, ], group='name', group.test=TRUE) # Change the condition within square brackets!
```